# python urllib usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I imported two libraries `urllib` and `from urllib.request import urlopen`.

The second  one is contained  in the first

When I went over the code and tried to remove the `from urllib.request import urlopen` line , I got this message:

```
opnerHTMLnum = urllib.request.build_opener()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

When I restore the `from urllib.request import urlopen` line the code runs .

Can anyone explain why?

```
import re
#import http.cookiejar
import os.path
#import time
#import urllib3
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# ...

    opnerHTMLnum = urllib.request.build_opener()
```

Comment: `from urllib.request import urlopen` gives
`ImportError: No module named request` on Python 2.7.
Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing python3 package `urllib.request` with Python2.7 one which is `urllib2`. Please don't do that. Python3 and Python2 are libraries are different. All you may want is `urllib2` from python2

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
req = Request("yoururl")
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I think the OP got confused with the tags; if he really was on Python 2.7, there would have been an import error, not the behaviour stated in the question.

Comment: Good catch, I was following this example: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html and I didn't realise the examples referred to python3. My env is Python 2.7. +1 voted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `urllib` package is just that, a package. It's `__init__.py` does not import `urllib.request` and thus you cannot simply reach `urllib.request` by only importing `urllib`. It is intended as a namespace only.

Import `urllib.request` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Both `import X` and `from X import Y` perform an import of whatever module or package `X` that is given.

In this case, `urllib` is a package. When you `import urllib`, then the package itself is imported, and you get a reference to it, but any submodules are not imported (in this case). When you do `from urllib.request import ...`, Python actually imports the entire module `urllib.request`, but then picks out the names that you asked for and gives you references to them.

If you aren't using `urlopen`, then you could also easily do `import urllib.request` and get the same result.